# Yarn unable to add packages (both inside and outside workspaces)

Tags: node.js, node-modules, yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces, yarnpkg-v2

## Yarn unable to add packages (both inside and outside workspaces)

Hi there, I'm using Yarn 2, I don't seem to be able to install *any* package. I always get the following formatted error:

```
$ yarn add useful-package

➤ BR0027: useful-package@unknown can't be resolved to a satisfying range
➤ Errors happened when preparing the environment required to run this command.
```

I have tried both inside a project that uses yarn's workspaces and outside in another test project.

This occurs with any package I try and Googling around I can't seem to find any relevant hits yet for this error message here.

What do you reckon the issue may be?

Best,
Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I'd hit a Node JS version conflict with Yarn 2.

Make sure to use latest Yarn (berry/2) with a node version V10.19.0 or greater.

I hope this helps someone!

Best,
Matt